# How apply semi transparent color material over object

Tags: 3dsmax

I have some 3D  objects (.max files) and I'd like to be able to apply a semi transparent (translucent/semi-opaque) colour wash over then so that the underdlying texture is still visible (i'd want to adjust the level of opacity and then choose a level that gives the right effect).

Could anyone advise what would be the simplest way to do this for a noob?

Many thanks,
John

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the "best" way but I assume you can achieve what you want using Composite Map
https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/3DSMax/files/GUID-850CFCCD-2DF9-4FC9-85F7-9A92AE0C0297-htm.html

Here are some tutorial I found on youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhom5CTFlRs&list=PLAA5GgIB3LY1hpiSBt-UUzoFJNX_3VuNu

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. Composite maps look really powerful. Following some more personal searching I think a key aspect for my requirement is using the alpha channel for some transparency/opacity. This link gives an example https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/getting-started/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/3DSMax-Tutorial/files/GUID-B7FB4366-7766-4A70-A2B0-5F6942E8E665-htm.html

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can use mix map & put underlying map in slot 1 & overlaying map in 2.
Then mix amount to 50.
In the overlaying map go to output & in output amount type 0.8
You will have a translucent material on top.
Hope this helps.
Thanks.